# snap 3D cursor to closest vertex in 2.8

Tags: vertices, shortcut, 3d-cursor

I'd like to put the 3D cursor on a vertex with a single action rather than a series of actions.

Currently, I have to switch to edit mode then switch to vertex select then select the vertex then cursor to selected than back to object mode.
It's very tedious.

I tried to hold ctrl while placing the 3D cursor near a vertex. It did not work.
I tried the magnet, chose vertex mode but it didn't work with 3D cursor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Snap to vertex works when cursor is selected in the toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

I got it now. If the magnet is active and snap to vertex is selected you need to hold and drag mouse to snap nearest vertex. If you just click it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With the snap tool enabled and in vertex snap mode, all you really need to do is first select the 'source' vertex, then hover your mouse cursor over the 'target' vertex, press <kbd>G</kbd> and left click to finalize the snap! No need to select and drag from one vertex to another. This comes in especially handy when snapping vertices that are far apart from each other!

Comment: Thanks, though the question was about how to snap the 3D cursor not another vertex.